# Output Filenames in a Folder to a Text File

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt

Using Windows Command Prompt or Windows PowerShell, how can I output all the file names in a single directory to a text file, without the file extension?

In Command Prompt, I was using:

```
dir /b > files.txt
```

### Result

```
01 - Prologue.mp3
02 - Title.mp3
03 - End.mp3
files.txt
```

### Desired Output

```
01 - Prologue
02 - Title
03 - End
```

Notice the "dir /b > files.txt" command includes the file extension and puts the filename at the bottom.

Without using a batch file, is there a clean Command Prompt or PowerShell command that can do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```sh
# Get-ChildItem (gci) is PowerShell's dir equivalent.
# -File limits the output to files.
# .BaseName extracts the file names without extension.
(Get-ChildItem -File).BaseName | Out-File files.txt
```

<sup>Note: You can use `dir` in PowerShell too, where it is simply an alias of `Get-ChildItem`. However, to avoid confusion with `cmd.exe`'s internal `dir` command, which has fundamentally different syntax, it's better to use the PowerShell-native alias, `gci`. To see all aliases defined for `Get-ChildItem`, run 
`Get-Alias -Definition Get-ChildItem`</sup>

Note that use of PowerShell's `>` redirection operator - which is effectively an alias of the 
[`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet - would also result in the undesired inclusion of the output, `files.txt`, in the enumeration, as in `cmd.exe` and POSIX-like shells such as `bash`, because the target file is created *first*.

By contrast, use of a pipeline with `Out-File` (or [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content), for text input) delays file creation until the cmdlet in this separate pipeline segment is initialized<sup>[1]</sup> - and because the file enumeration in the first segment has by definition already completed by that point, due to the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call being enclosed in `(...)`, the output file is *not* included in the enumeration.

Also note that property access `.BaseName` was applied to *all*  files returned by `(Get-ChildItem ...)`, which conveniently resulted in an array of the individual files' property values being returned, thanks to a feature called [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

Character-encoding note:

- In Windows PowerShell, `Out-File` / `>` creates "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files, whereas `Set-Content` uses the system's legacy ANSI code page.
- In PowerShell (Core) 7+, BOM-less UTF-8 is the consistent default.

The `-Encoding` parameter can be used to control the encoding explicitly.

---

<sup>[1] In the case of `Set-Content`, it is actually delayed even further, namely until the first input object is received, but that is an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied on.</sup>

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the detail and explanation. I ended up using (Get-ChildItem -File).BaseName | Out-File files.txt -Encoding utf8, as UTF-8 encoding is important to me. Thanks for pointing out the -Encoding parameter.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @GTSJoe; my pleasure, and thanks for a well-formulated question. Please see my latest updates re aliases and the feature called _member enumeration_.